# How to get the count of the number of files were dropped in an input type file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepond

I want to get a count of the number of files, Its working fine when I select files, but when I use drag and drop onchange is not working.
I'm using filepond for image uploading.

Below is my code

```
<input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" maxFiles="24" multiple data-allow-reorder="true" data-max-file-size="15MB" data-allow-reorder="true" allowImageResize accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/webp, image/svg"/>
```

Below is my JS function

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
  {
    $('input[type=file]').on('change',function () {
    fileCount = this.files.length;
    var firstLength = 100/fileCount;
    alert(firstLength );
  });
});
```

I found below code from stack

```
$("#imageUpload").on('change drop', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var files = $(this)[0].files;
  alert(files.length);
});
```

Above code give this error in console.
**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"**

Any lead is appreciated.

Comment: What does `alert(firstLength)` show?

Comment: Its working fine when I select images, but when I use drag and drop the onchange function is not getting called

Comment: The files from drop event is stored in `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer`. Check out this example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLe65ut4/9/